# How can I experience CPU steal time on co-existent VMs?

Tags: performance, openstack, cpu, multi-core

I've already had an Openstack cloud with two compute nodes each having 8 physical cores. I intend to make a scene that two or more VMs contend for the same shared core on a single host so **`CPU steal time (%st)`** metric for any of them shows none zero amount. So far no such luck. I launched two VMs with only one vcpu and placed them on the same core of one host and deployed high load on one (using stress or other utilities) while running CPU intensive application on the other and observing `top` command on both but `%st` always remains zero!. I don't know why there's no contention (or as they define `CPU steal time` why there's no involuntarily wait for getting the CPU) on any of the VMs!

Anyone know how I can set up a senario that there would be some non zero amount for `%st`?

Comment: I did not have any trouble creating steal time on a VM, as reported by top. However, I had to load the host CPUs to do it, not another VM.

Comment: Thank you for responding. But our experiment is intended to observe the adverse impact that VMs on the same core may have on one another (known as VM performance overhead due to interference). I wonder how to cause it in this manner!

Comment: O.K. so if instead I make 3 VM's and load them all down, I observe significant %st on each VM. I suppose the difference between us might be that i am using kvm/qemu and not Openstack.

Comment: [screen shot](https://imgur.com/a/Hjuca).

Comment: I'm so thankful for your attention. As far as I know Openstack uses the libvert which is a part of kvm/qeum too. Would you please tell me which OS you have on your VMs & the host & what version their kernels are?

Comment: Host = Ubuntu 16.04.1 server: Kernel: 4.10.0-rc1-k410fixed, which is -rc1 + 3 commits after to fix a bad mistake (this is just what I was running at the time, mainline, compiled myself); serv-tt VM = Ubuntu 16.04.1 server: Kernel 4.4.0-57-generic; desk-dev VM = Ubuntu 16.04 desktop, unity: Kernel 4.4.0-53-generic; serv-tt VM: Ubuntu 14.04.5 server: Kernel 4.2.0-42-generic. All are 64 bit computers, and all VMs have 4 vcpus, while the host has 8 (an older model i7-2600k).